# iOS Messages App UITableViewCell Insert Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

What I am wondering is how I can go about achieving an animation like the iOS Messages app animation whenever YOU send a message. The animation takes the text from the text field inside inputaccessoryview and animates to the uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try this CocoaControl, gives you a full Messaging UI like iOS one.

I really tried to find the animation code and I achieved this (is not even the close solution, I didnt find where that Observer is called):

```
- (void)finishSendingMessageAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

   UITextView *textView = self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView;
    textView.text = nil;
    [textView.undoManager removeAllActions];

    [self.inputToolbar toggleSendButtonEnabled];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:textView];

    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:[JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext context]];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    if (self.automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage) {
        [self scrollToBottomAnimated:animated];
    }
}
```

If you really want to achieve the animation you may wanna check the full Control, or just implement it.

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Hope it Helps!